# How to resolve "LUA script parse/execute error" during Freeswitch installation?

Tags: linux, debian, freeswitch

```
2016-10-24 02:37:33.733197 [INFO] mod_dialplan_xml.c:637 Processing 1985922714 <1985922714>->4595609013 in context default
2016-10-24 02:37:33.753200 [ERR] switch_odbc.c:368 STATE: 01000 CODE 0 ERROR: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so' : file not found

2016-10-24 02:37:33.753200 [CRIT] switch_core_sqldb.c:508 Failure to connect to ODBC ASTPP!
2016-10-24 02:37:33.753200 [ERR] freeswitch_lua.cpp:367 Connection failed.  DBH NOT Connected.
2016-10-24 02:37:33.753200 [ERR] freeswitch_lua.cpp:460 DBH NOT Connected.
2016-10-24 02:37:33.753200 [ERR] mod_lua.cpp:203 /usr/local/freeswitch/scripts/astpp/lib/astpp.functions.lua:32: assertion failed!
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'assert'
        /usr/local/freeswitch/scripts/astpp/lib/astpp.functions.lua:32: in function 'load_conf'
        /usr/local/freeswitch/scripts/astpp/astpp.lua:49: in main chunk
2016-10-24 02:37:33.753200 [ERR] mod_lua.cpp:270 LUA script parse/execute error!
2016-10-24 02:37:33.753200 [CRIT] mod_dptools.c:1713 WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING
2016-10-24 02:37:33.753200 [CRIT] mod_dptools.c:1713 Open /usr/local/freeswitch/conf/vars.xml and change the default_password.
2016-10-24 02:37:33.753200 [CRIT] mod_dptools.c:1713 Once changed type 'reloadxml' at the console.
```

Comment: you didn;t specify any details about your installation. Also, the error `Can't open lib '/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so' : file not found` is very straightforward, and you need to be able to administer your system if you want to install software.

Comment: The problem is with your Lua script, you are not able to connect to database. Please go through the Lua script that you are calling and you can also post the script code here.

Comment: What did you run to cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

here is my fix:

run:

```
[root@astpp-v3 ~]# cat /etc/odbc.ini
[ASTPP]
Driver = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
SERVER = localhost
PORT = 3306
DATABASE = astpp
USERNAME = root
PASSWORD = lozycv
OPTION = 67108864
**Socket = /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock**
```

then run:

```
[root@astpp-v3 ~]# cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
**socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock**
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

and note the correct path for mysql.sock and updatethe odbc.ini file with it.

Answer (score 0):

Please run below command to verify mysql connection with freeswitch

```
[isql -v ASTPP]
```